# Picard SortSam speed up?

Tags: sorting, bioinformatics, picard

I'm wondering how to speed up picard's SortSam? It takes a long time to run it and I know GATK can be multi-threaded but I have not found example on Picard yet.

I'm wondering how other people tackle this problem?

Comment: You might consider using samtools sort instead of Picard.  You can use multiple CPU threads with samtools sort.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, sorting a random BAM file can't be speed up due to the nature of the problem. That's why the tool doesn't offer multithreading.